# Text should not align itself on change in parent element's width

Tags: html, css

I have simple p element in a div.

What I want is the text in p should not align itself on change in div's width.

like if the div's width is 100vw, and then it is decreased to 20vw (with some animation), then the text should be same as before (with hidden overflow), means the text should not align itself by going in next line and so on.

I tried using `position:fixed` in p, but then `overflow-x:hidden` does not work.

Comment: provide some of the original source

Comment: Something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/25f0wrm8/)?

Comment: @pol yes yes..thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). You can set it to `nowrap` for your `p` element for the text to not wrap when the width of parent `div` is reduced

```css
div {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.a {
  width: 200px;
}

.b {
  width: 50px;
}
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `white-space: pre` to your `p` element.

**EDIT:** Sinstein's solution above using `white-space: nowrap` works if you want to keep all of your text in one line only. You should use `pre` if you want to keep the existing line breaks.